# Checking networok connectivity between two hosts

Tags: shell, unix, networking

I want to have a generic shell script which will check network connectivity between two hosts.

I wrote shell script with `host` and `nslookup` command to get the more details of target host, with these command I can't determine if current host can talk to target host.

Also I can't use(restricted) `ping` command , I was wondering if can use some other command to check network connectivity betweenn two hosts

Please suggest

Comment: What type of connectivity do you want to test for? What/were are the hosts?

Comment: Network connectivity .Given a target host to determine if source host can communicate to target host

Answer (score 1):

> Given a target host to determine if source host can communicate to target host

This is too vague to be useful. To solve this problem, you need to nail down what you mean by "communicate." A host may be able to send ICMP but not TCP. It may be able to send TCP but not ICMP. It may be able to send TCP to port 80, but not to 22. It may be able to send HTTP to port 80, but not SSH to port 80. Packets you send may return an error, or they may be silently dropped. The endpoint may receive your packets, but not process them. It may process them but not respond to you. There are many levels of "communicate."

So the best thing to test with is the thing you actually want to do. So if you want to communicate with HTTP over port 80, the best test is to do that. In fact, the best test is to just do the thing you wanted to do and not check beforehand. You're going to have to deal with errors no matter way. Just because you checked beforehand doesn't mean your actual attempt will be successful.

But sometimes you do just want to check "connectivity" (for some value of "connectivity") for monitoring purposes. In that case, again, do the thing you want. The easiest shell tool for checking HTTP connectivity is to fetch something with `curl`. If you need some other port, then a very nice generic solution is `netcat` (often called `nc`). I like:

```
nc -G 1 <host> <port> </dev/null
```

A return code of 0 means it connected; 1 means it failed.

For more esoteric issues, you can use `nmap` or even `hping` to craft about anything you want.

But most of the time, you shouldn't check at all. And if you do check, check with the thing you really want to do.